# GLSurfaceView renderer, how to force surface re-creation?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a `GLSurfaceView` renderer and method `onSurfaceCreated` is called only once (basically only when activity is created or re-created).

I need to test behavior when EGL context is lost and surface is recreated during normal activity life cycle, however I am unable to put app into such situation no matter what I do.

Is there anything that I can do to simulate situation in which is `onSurfaceCreated` called again? How to make my app lose EGL context?

**Edit: After a few days I noticed that the problem was gone and the app started to behave properly as said in specs:**

```
public abstract void onSurfaceCreated (GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
Called when the surface is created or recreated.
Called when the rendering thread starts and whenever the EGL context is lost.
The EGL context will typically be lost when the Android device awakes 
after going to sleep
```

Before that, every time the device went to sleep, the activity was destroyed and recreated on awake which was preventing me to test if the code in `OnSurfaceCreated` worked well.

Now it behaves much better when sleep/awake occurs - it usually does not destroy the activity and just calls `OnSurfaceCreated` method which is the situation I was aiming for.

Comment: Only thing I can think of would be changing the GLSurfaceView size by View layout mechanisms and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, [GLSurfaceView.Renderer.onSurfaceCreated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html#onSurfaceCreated%28javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10,%20javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig%29) is called when the surface is created or recreated.

Called when the rendering thread starts and whenever the EGL context is lost. **The EGL context will typically be lost when the Android device awakes after going to sleep.**

Have you tried locking your device's screen and unlocking it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. It appears that the docs are quite right about this situation and I have tried this before posted a question. However, my app acted strangely as described in my updated question. Since you have answered the question first I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but the only thing that i can think of is to switch the `GLSUrfaceView` with a new one using the same `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`.
That should create a new EGL context and call the `onSurfaceCreated()` a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can look at `onScreenStateChanged` method but it's available for API 16 or higher. If you mean "pausing and resuming the activity" by "normal activity life ciycle" maybe you can use `onPause` or `onResume` to track this.

What exactly do you want to do with `onSurfaceCreated()` ? You can force the rendering by `requestRender()` method of `SurfaceView` and do the necessary calculations inside `onDrawFrame()` of `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In OnSurfaceCreated I am loading and reloading textures and hardware vertex buffers. Essentially, a simple code but I needed to test it in the real world scenario.
However, the problem is resolved, you can see the details in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your view is in a fragment, you can detach and re-attach the fragment.